# No such command 'sip show peers' when using asterisk

Tags: networking, command-line, virtualbox, asterisk

i want to connect two soft phone using asterisk after configuration the `sip.conf` and `iax.conf` and `extension.conf`  can't enter any order from cli
example of the error:

```
Connected to Asterisk 11.6-cert1 currently running on fedo-VirtualBox 
(pid = 1066)
fedo-VirtualBox*CLI> sip show peers
No such command 'sip show peers' (type 'core show help sip show' for
other possible commands)
```

Comment: when you run `asterisk` or maybe `asterisk -rm` for the CLI, what are the results for `sip show peers`?  Paste actual output please.

Comment: It seems that in later versions, `sip` is being replaced by `pjsip`, but I don't see any similar command for it (`core show help pjsip`). :(

Comment: I think the new command is `pjsip show endpoints`! Newer version, new commands. Dear God!

Comment: You use a different config file too (`pjsip.conf`)!

Answer (score 12):

```
module show like sip
```

is returning something?

if not do this

```
module load chan_sip.so
```

and try again

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above answer and it still failed.
Reason was: chan_sip.so was not there in modules folder.

So, I uninstalled the asterisk

```
make uninstall
```

Then I started installing the asterisk-13 again

```
./configure
make menuconfig
```

In menu select, go to channel drivers option and check the checkbox `chan_sip` [Probably unchecked]. Then, do the below command

```
make & make install & make config
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have installed asterisk through yum so recompiling will not work for me so i search yum repo for chan_sip.so

```
[root@MTL-189551 asterisk]# yum whatprovides */chan_sip.so
```

Note it is very necessary to install the correct version of the module i have installed **Asterisk 13.17.2** so it is very necessary to install same module

In yum search result i found this version

```
asterisk-sip-13.17.2-vici.el7.centos.x86_64 : Legacy SIP channel driver for 

Asterisk
Repo        : goautodial-updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/asterisk/modules/chan_sip.so

[root@MTL-189551 asterisk]# yum install asterisk-sip-13.17.2
```

Before restart asterisk add below line

```
[root@MTL-189551 ~]# vim /etc/asterisk/modules.conf

Find the below line in file and uncomment or add 
require = chan_sip.so
```

After this restart your asterisk and connect to asterisk console and check whether module is loaded or not

```
    MTL-189551*CLI> module show like chan_sip.so
Module                         Description                              Use Count  Status      Support Level
chan_sip.so                    Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)        0          Running              core
1 modules loaded
MTL-189551*CLI>
```